# Trouble Booting Ubuntu from bootable USB

Tags: system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu from a bootable USB, but having trouble. I've created the USB according to the tutorial, but when I restart my computer with the USB inserted, all I get is a black screen with a single white line. How can I get my Windows 10 computer to boot from the USB?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem couple of times myself, while installing linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ). And most of time I have managed to resolve it by changing the utility used to create a bootable USB.
since you have not mentioned the method you chose to create the bootable USB, my recommendation is to give [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) a try, in case you have not already.
For me personally Rufus has been the savior of the day, and it's quite easy to utilize.
Hope this helps